# Конвертирование SVG в XML для использования в Android приложении

Tags: android, android-studio, xml, svg, android-drawable

Использую **Android Studio** для разработки мобильного приложения. Дизайн мобильного приложения сделан из SVG компонентов. В Android Studio есть [стандартный способ конвертации SVG в XML](https://streletzcoder.ru/konvertacziya-svg-v-vector-drawable-v-android-studio/) но он **конвертирует** SVG в XML **некорректно** (То есть, стандартный способ от Android Studio работает, но не полностью, получается изображение с отсутствием некоторых фрагментов) . Знаю, что какие-то фрагменты в SVG не поддерживаются в XML, но какие именно фрагменты - не знаю.

**Я пробовал**

-https://inloop.github.io/svg2android

-https://products.aspose.app/pdf/ru/conversion/svg-to-xml

**Я НЕ пробовал, потому что платно**

-https://svg2vector.com

**Вопрос**

Как конвертировать SVG в XML без потери некоторых фрагментов изображения? Есть ли для этого утилиты или сайты? Если это не возможно, то какие есть альтернативы?

**Пример файла, который нужно конвертировать из SVG а XML**

-https://drive.google.com/file/d/10lS9WcQGRLIfpqrHgfhgtIVWpakBmL37/view?usp=sharing

Если конвертировать файл не удаётся, подскажите, что конкретно не так в этом файле.

Comment: Нужно точно править именно SVG. Инструментов, которые любой SVG нормально в XML для AS сделают - нет. Но вот что править надо - не подскажу, не дизайнер)